# How to constantly run Google Colaboratory at a specific time every day?

Tags: python, schedule, google-colaboratory

I recently have built a Python program that runs on Google Colaboratory that retrieves the data from a site. Since I wanted to create a graph based on data of one month, I want to retrieve the data every day. Is there any way to run this on Google Colab, because my friend would like to fix the code at some time too? If not, is there a way to perform this on Windows 10?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: How did you end up solving this?

Comment: The accepted answer is no longer accurate. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Colab doesn't support this currently.

For Windows 10, I think you're looking for the [Task Scheduler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383614(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 10):

This has changed now that I created [colabctl](https://github.com/TensorTom/colabctl).

You can use colabctl to run your Google Colaboratory notebooks from the CLI, on a schedule if you wish. Simply add `colabctl.py` to a cron job.

**Note:** If you want to run it on a headless server, you will first need to run it once from your desktop to save your login cookie to the pickle file and then upload that pickle to your server along with colabctl.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Does it still work?